# ruby net/sftp getting write error on uploading file to remote

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm trying to copy files from one pc to a local nas server.
The below works so there is no errors with the connection

```
 @connection = Net::SFTP.start(host, username, :password => serverpassword)
 @connection.dir.foreach("/media/MediaShare") do |entry|
    puts entry.longname
 end
```

This on the other hand does not work:

```
       local = '/home/ubuntu64/Videos/myfile.avi'
       remote = '/media/MediaShare/myfile.avi'

       @connection.upload!(local, remote)



    upload.rb:331:in `on_write': Net::SFTP::StatusException
    write/media/MediaShare/myfile.avi (4, "failure") (Net::SFTP::StatusException)
```

now if i create and do the same with a 1kb file size it moves without a problem, which leads me to think if there is a file limit?

Answer (score 0):

`Net::SFTP` doesn't have any limitation on file size as i know. But if your server is using nginx or apache there could be limitations (for nginx defaults 50 MB) or sftp user on remote machine could have limitations.